# POST Content-Length exceeds the limit

Tags: php

I get similar errors in my error_log in php when users are uploading their files

> PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 11933650 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0

In my php.ini (created custom ini file in public_html) would this solve this problem, how much would I have to set it to around 1GB? I am going to change my settings to this in php.ini, will it solve the problem?

```
upload_max_filesize = 1000M ;1GB
post_max_size = 1000M
```

What would I set the 'memory_limit' limit to.

Also would this be correct in my script to check file uploaded size is <1GB

```
if($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["size"]<1000000)
```

Comment: Are you sure you are editing the correct php.ini?

Comment: Are you editing the correct php.ini (there are several)? Is something else resetting the settings? (e.g. any calls to `php_ini_set`?)

Comment: I created a custom php.ini file in public_html

Comment: @daza: you can't just drop a php.ini anywhere you want.PHP only checks certain locations, and "current directory" isn't one of them. You can use 'php_value' directives in your httpd.conf and/or an .htaccess file to set in a particular directory. But otherwise you'll have to change it in the main .ini file. Use `php_info()` to see what your "local" settings are, and which .ini files are being used.

Comment: make an info.php with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` copy it to public_html and call it in your browser. Then check if upload_max_filesize has the right value.

Comment: my phpinfo() says its correct now changed to upload_max_filesize = 1000M and post_max_size = 1000M. Should that solve this issue now?

Comment: Make sure you're updating the correct php.ini: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58999601/470749

Answer (score 102, accepted):

8388608 bytes is 8M, the default limit in PHP. Those changes to php.ini should indeed solve the problem (make sure your restart your Apache server after making them).

Memory limit shouldn't need to be changed here.

Comment: Make sure you restart your server after making the changes in .ini file.

Comment: If you are using nginx+php fpm make sure to restart the php daemon  `sudo service php5-fpm restart`

Comment: The restart did it for me. +1 Thanks ;)

Comment: Let me just post here my experience, the restart gave me a `stop: Unknown instance:`, it was just creating a new php5-fpm instance but my webserver was still using the old one, I then had to do `sudo killall -KILL php5-fpm` then `sudo service php5-fpm start`

Comment: Depending on what else is being done in the PHP process that handles the upload, it may be necessary to increase `memory_limit` to an amount larger than the desired max upload size.

Answer (score 49):

I suggest that you should change to `post_max_size` from 8M to 32M in the `php.ini` file.

Answer (score 44):

you just setting at php.ini

then set :

```
upload_max_filesize = 1000M;
post_max_size = 1000M;
```

then restart your xampp..
Check the image

[image]

Answer (score 20):

Try pasting this to .htaccess and it should work.

```
php_value post_max_size 2000M
php_value upload_max_filesize 2500M
php_value max_execution_time 6000000
php_value max_input_time 6000000
php_value memory_limit 2500M
```

Comment: Can you be little bit more specific? should it be outsite IfModule or inside.
i've pasted it outside IfModule and it is giving me server error.

Answer (score 14):

**post_max_size** should be slightly bigger than **upload_max_filesize**, because when uploading using HTTP POST method the text also includes headers with file size and name, etc.

If you want to successfully uppload 1GiB files, you have to set:

```
upload_max_filesize = 1024M
post_max_size = 1025M
```

Note, the correct suffix for GB is G, i.e. upload_max_filesize = 1G.

No need to set **memory_limit**.

Comment: This is the one that saved me.

Answer (score 7):

In Some cases, you need to increase the maximum execution time.

```
max_execution_time=30
```

I made it

```
max_execution_time=600000
```

then I was happy.

Comment: often you may not want to do this in php.ini because it would allow ALL php processes to run for that amount of time.  You can set it in a single file with set_time_limit() e.g. set_time_limit(600000)

Answer (score 5):

There might be more than just one *php.ini* file. For example, when using WAMP there are 2 *php.ini* files in following directories:

- `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin`
- `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12`

You need to edit the first one.

Answer (score 5):

I disagree, but the solution to increase the file size in `php.ini` or `.htaccess` won't work if the user sends a file larger than allowed by the server application.

I suggest validating this on the front end. For example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $ ('#your_input_file_id').bind('change', function() {
        var fileSize = this.files[0].size/1024/1024;
        if (fileSize > 2) { // 2M
            alert('Your custom message for max file size exceeded');
            $('#your_input_file_id').val('');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Disagree with what?

Comment: It's fine to validate client side, but it doesn't do anything for security, only to give the user an immediate warning if they're uploading a large file. The whole objective here isn't to keep users from uploading a large file, it's to allow them to upload a large file.

Comment: Is there no server side solution/check to this? I can easily bypass a JS check.

Comment: Nvm, figured it out: `if ($_SERVER["CONTENT_LENGTH"] > (int)(str_replace("M", "", ini_get("post_max_size")) * 1024 * 1024)) { // do w/e`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Php 5.6.X versions in windows using Wamp, then file location may be in,

`C:\Windows\php.ini`

Just try with

```
post_max_size = 100M;
```

Try to do changes in Apache one. By that your Wamp/XAMP load .ini file

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel and using **artisan:serve** for running Laravel project you create **php.ini** in your public directory, then you can specify your configuration.

- file_uploads = On
- max_execution_time = 300
- post_max_size = 20480M
- upload_max_filesize = 20480M