# PHP Warning: POST Content-Length of 8978294 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0

Tags: wordpress, xampp, php

I am getting this error when trying to upload an import on WordPress on my XAMPP local dev environment:

Warning: POST Content-Length of 8978294 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0

I changed the `upload_max_filesize` from `2M` to `1000M`, but that didn't seem to do anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try increasing post_max_size to 20M

Comment: If you are considering just a WP upload - just increase the post_max_size(all the current uploads together) and possibly upload_max_filesize(for single file)... however if you want to hide the error if someone would try to upload too large files (over your limits) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21704930/how-to-prevent-warning-post-content-length-and-memory-size

Comment: a note to passersby: this error and fix is not specific to WordPress or XAMPP. It is applicable generally to the PHP error `POST Content-Length of X bytes exceeds the limit of Y`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [POST Content-Length exceeds the limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279897/post-content-length-exceeds-the-limit)

Comment: Make sure you're updating the correct php.ini: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58999601/470749

Answer (score 453, accepted):

8388608 bytes is 8M, the default limit in PHP. Update your `post_max_size` in php.ini to a larger value.

`upload_max_filesize` sets the max file size that a user can upload while
`post_max_size` sets the maximum amount of data that can be sent via a POST in a form.

So you can set `upload_max_filesize` to 1 meg, which will mean that the biggest single file a user can upload is 1 megabyte, but they could upload 5 of them at once if the `post_max_size` was set to 5.

Changes will take effect after a restart of the server.

Comment: Also make sure you check .htaccess file for the same values that might 've been overridden

Comment: I had an issue that I forgot to set the units 'M' - Megabytes, Thanks a  lot !

Comment: Without restarting Xamp, it doesn't worked for me. Maybe obvious for advanced PHP dev. but it wasn't for me.

Comment: For nginx you may need to restart php7.2-fpm.service. Any fast CGI server.

Comment: Please do not forgot to restart the apache tomcat server, if you use XAMPP for local environment

Comment: You should also provide the sample code snippet to describe how actually it works.

Answer (score 78):

Just set these in php.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize = 1000M;
post_max_size = 1000M;
```

Comment: Nowadays the filename would most definitely be `.user.ini`

Answer (score 36):

***1.*** **First u will find the php.ini file.**

> u can find **php.ini** file from this path.    **C:\xampp\php**    or from
>   **xampp** folder.

***2.*** **Now open php.ini file and change the following:**

> **1.** ***post-max-size*** (change **8M** to **800M**).
>
> **2.** ***upload-max-filesize*** (change **2M** to **2000M**).

***3.*** **Now stop the Apache server and MySQL.**

***4.*** **Now restart Apache server and MySQL.**

It worked fine after that.

Enjoy ur working now :)

Answer (score 23):

That's an 8MB `post_max_size` error.

Set it to a value you're comfortable with.

Answer (score 19):

You will have to change the value of

```
post-max-size
upload-max-filesize
```

both of which you will find in **php.ini**

Restarting your server will help it start working. On a local test server running XAMIP, i had to stop the Apache server and restart it. It worked fine after that.

Answer (score 16):

Already restarted your Webserver?

This will force php to reload the `php.ini`

Answer (score 14):

1. Create new text file in your `wp-admin` directory root and name it `info.php`.
2. Open `info.php` and add this line:

   `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`
3. Save it.
4. Go to `yourwebsitename(probably localhost)/wp-admin/info.php` in any web-browser.
5. On the 8th line you will see: **Configuration File (php.ini) Path**, in my case it is `C:\Windows`, meaning it is located on my C drive.
6. In the 9th line you will see: **Loaded Configuration File**, and next to it is written `C:\xampp\php.ini`

So I found my `php.ini` page that is associated with my wordpress web-site.

7. Go to that path, and find `php.ini`.
8. Open it, and edit:

   Search for `post_max_size=8M`, and change it to `post_max_size=1000M`

   Search for `upload_max_filesize=2M`, and change it to `upload_max_filesize=1000M`
9. Go back to your Admin page → Media → Add New
10. On the bottom you will see that 2MB has changed to 1000M.

Once you done this process then you must restart your web server or just restart your computer.

Comment: A worthy comment as other answers kind of assume you know where your php.ini is, and not editing the right file is a good source of these kinds of problems.

Comment: Thx. Addition: I had to restart httpd service afterwards.

Comment: Thaks for guidance. I watched step by step and it's worked

Answer (score 11):

Go to `C:\xamppp\php`. Set these values in php.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize = 1000M
post_max_size = 0M
```

Answer (score 8):

for anyone running [PHPMyAdmin](https://hub.docker.com/_/phpmyadmin) inside of docker.
Set the `UPLOAD_LIMIT` value in the env

from the docs https://github.com/phpmyadmin/docker#environment-variables-summary

> `UPLOAD_LIMIT` - if set, this option will override the default value
> for apache and php-fpm (format as `[0-9+](K,M,G)` default value is
> 2048K, this will change `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`
> values)

docker-compose.yml example:

```
phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      - UPLOAD_LIMIT=300M
```

normal docker run:

```
sudo docker run .... -e UPLOAD_LIMIT=300M
```

For both of these options you have to rebuild the container

Comment: This one fixed my error

Answer (score 7):

1. Find php.ini [\xampp\php]
2. Just set these in php.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize = 1000M;
post_max_size = 1000M;
```

3. Rebot server

   - Stop Apache and MySQL
   - Start again Apache and MySQL

Answer (score 6):

Using wamp do the following and hopefully, it will resolve an issue

Make these changes in PHP Options to correct:

```
max_execution_time   180

memory_limit   512M or your highest available

post_max_size  32M

upload_max_filesize   64M
```

Answer (score 5):

Go to

```
C:\drive\xampp(where xampp installed)
```

simply find php.ini file then in the file search

```
post_max_size=XXM
upload_max_size=XXM
```

Change with this code

```
post_max_size=100M
upload_max_filesize=100M
```

Don't forget to restart the xampp

Answer (score 4):

You also need the change [post-max-size](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size).

Answer (score 4):

From the XAMPP panel, click on the ADMIN button on the Apache site.
Then choose to edit php.ini
And add the missing post_max_size to a value you are comfortable with.

```
post_max_size = 100M
```

Answer (score 4):

I have fixed same issue by changing below parameters to expected value in **/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini** file

```
upload_max_filesize = 8M;
post_max_size = 8M;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
upload_max_filesize = 8M;
post_max_size = 8M;
```

Imagine you already changed above values. But what happen when user try to upload large files greater than 8M ?

This is what happen, PHP shows this warning!

```
Warning: POST Content-Length of x bytes exceeds the limit of y bytes in Unknown on line 0
```

you can avoid it by adding

```
ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to

```
C:\ drive
```

or that drive where xampp is installed
click on xampp
find php and open it , there you find `php.ini` folder 
open php.ini file with notepad and find `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in both "up and down find option",change both values to `1000M`

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 options for this error:

1. The file you are uploading is too big, which you need to use smaller file.
2. Increase the upload size in php.ini to

`upload_max_filesize = 9M; post_max_size = 9M;`

Comment: I'll spare you the downvote as I'm sure you're trying to bump your reputation high enough to have useful privileges on this site, but this answer doesn't provide anything new or valuable that hasn't been said and upvoted many years prior.

Answer (score 2):

Go to browser and search for `php.ini` and then open it, and change these two values:

```
post_max_size= 1000000000000M
```

```
upload_max_filesize= 10000000000000M
```

If you open the `php.ini` file using notepad , you can search for these two values by clicking:
<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You might not be uploading the right zip file. In my case, as a newbie to wordpress(I used to do hardcoding), I installed the zipped file that contained another zip file which is the actual theme neede to be upload. So what what need to do in this case is to unzip the file and locate the "theme_name.zip" inside.

Answer (score 1):

If changing the post_max_size settings from `XAMPP` folders. It did not work for you try this.

From `XAMPP` control panel, click config then `PHP (php.ini)` and edit `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` to a higher number in this file instead. Stop Apache server. Start Apache server. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If your objective is to import a theme into your Wordpress then you can manually copy paste your theme into your wp-content->themes folder and extract it of course. I just encountered this and couldn't locate the php.ini file for WAMP.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my php7 issues on centos 7 by updating `/etc/php.ini` with these settings:

```
 post_max_size = 500M
 upload_max_filesize = 500M
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Optimaz ID](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5719038/optimaz-id) pointed out, the code below helped me hide the PHP error message in a case where the user uploads a file larger than the upload_max_filesize and post_max_size set in php.ini (which is almost impossible when a large value is set).

```
ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Answer (score -1):

Warning: POST Content-Length of 9649253 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0
The link you followed has expired.