# PHP image uploader error handling

Tags: php

Hi I have a PHP image uploader on my page. all the common image formats are allowed to insert in to the database. However when I try to insert another 'non allowed' format (I tried a video) via the upload, I get an error message as below.

```
Warning: POST Content-Length of 17917021 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0
```

can some one pls tell me what causing this error and possibly how do I correct this?

If my code is required pls do highlight.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Warning: POST Content-Length of 8978294 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719495/php-warning-post-content-length-of-8978294-bytes-exceeds-the-limit-of-8388608-b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to adjust your php.ini settings there are two settings.

```
upload_max_filesize
max_post_size
```

Comment: Thanks @DevZer0.. Also could u pls tell me how do I locate php.ini file

Comment: Oh i think I've got php.ini-development and php.ini-production

Comment: when you run `phpinfo()` it will tell you the active configuration file that is in use. @JohnEnglish

Comment: One last question for you, If I change the upload_max_filesize to 3M and if a user tries to upload a file larger that 3M still I'll get the same issue right? Can u suggest me a validation?

Comment: you can possibly check the Content-Length header and see if the file being uploaded is bigger than what you accept.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the error has nothing to do with the image format you are trying to upload, it has to do with the max file size your server allows you to upload.

You will find an anwer at [PHP change the maximum upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

Answer (score 0):

look into php.ini, this may interest you

```
upload_max_filesize
post_max_size
max_input_time
```