# If I want to upload the video then save it to new folder

Tags: php

I have made my upload form in my html file but when it tries to load, there is an error prompt:

> Warning: POST Content-Length of 76523900 bytes exceeds the limit of
>   8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0.

I am hoping for all positive response. Thank You :)

My code is:

```
<form name="video" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
  <input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000000000000000" type="hidden"/>
  <input type="file" name="uploadvideo" />
  <input type="submit" name="upload" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
```

Comment: Did you try and google the error? It's a very common thing.

Comment: html code 
<form name="video" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
<input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000000000000000"  type="hidden"/>
<input type="file" name="uploadvideo" />
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Warning: POST Content-Length of 8978294 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719495/php-warning-post-content-length-of-8978294-bytes-exceeds-the-limit-of-8388608-b)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value of **upload_max_filesize** and post_max_size in your php.ini

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = size

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = size
```

Comment: Thanks but still doesn't work. Do you have a sample code for this?

Comment: @junerd did you remember to reload / restart apache / nginx ?

Comment: Can you restart apache services @junerd