# Can't install wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, themes

I downloaded the theme from the website and want to install it. But it said

Warning: POST Content-Length of 24413939 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0
Are you sure you want to do this?

Please try again.

I press try again, and it back to the control panel and nothing happen, so how can I install the theme successfully?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Warning: POST Content-Length of 8978294 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719495/php-warning-post-content-length-of-8978294-bytes-exceeds-the-limit-of-8388608-b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your php.ini file following variable:

`post_max_size`

### OR

If php.ini not accessible try pasting your theme directly under `wp-content/themes` directory and it will appear on your dashboard->themes.