# i want to upload video in codeigniter which max length is 200mb but i got error of max length even i set max length 200M in php.ini

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
public function add_video()
{
    if(isset($_POST['add']) && $_POST['add']=='ADD')
    {

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['video']['tmp_name'],'uploadimg/'.$_FILES['video']['name']);

        $data = array('id'=>'', 'title'=>$_POST['title'],'video'=>$_FILES['video']['name'],'url'=>$_POST['link'],'status'=>$_POST['status'],'date'=>$_POST['date']);

        $this->Dbfunction->insertdata('videos',$data); 

        redirect(base_url().'index.php/admin/videos');
    }
}
```

**And I Got Following Error**

**Warning: POST Content-Length of 177938307 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0**

**Database Table Structure is follows**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoArt.png)

Comment: You need to define more than `200M` in php.ini

Comment: i define 200M in php.ini after that also i got same error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Warning: POST Content-Length of 8978294 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719495/php-warning-post-content-length-of-8978294-bytes-exceeds-the-limit-of-8388608-b)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set upload_max_filesize and post_max_size to 0 in php.ini

Comment: @KunalWaghmare have u restarted the server after changes?

Comment: @KunalWaghmare plz share the front end code in your question

Answer (score 0):

Create a file in PHP containing:

**file.php**

> <----------- start -------------->

```
<?php

phpinfo();
```

> <----------- end -------------->

Locate the line (Core): upload_max_filesize

If it is not the value you set in the php.ini file, or you changed the wrong file, or you did not restart apache

> Also remember that you need to increase **[post_max_size](http://php.net/post_max_size)** and **[memory_limit](http://php.net/memory_limit)** too.

Comment: but which code i write in that php file can you explain it?

Comment: Only "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" Save within the root mass of your web server and open http://localhost/file.php