# error on upload file < 1GB

Tags: php, forms, file, upload

I want to upload file from form and file size must be less then 1 GB. But there is an error like

> Warning: POST Content-Length of 38001905 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0**

What am I missing here?

Here is my code:

1. config: [Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHsIC.png)
2. input file: [input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98PIe.png)

Comment: Don't use screenshots to show us the code but add the code in the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the maximum upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

Comment: instead of putting screenshots of your code in the question, you should put your code itself, so it's easier for helpers here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Warning: POST Content-Length of 8978294 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719495/php-warning-post-content-length-of-8978294-bytes-exceeds-the-limit-of-8388608-b)

Answer (score 0):

The default maximum post data size in PHP is 8MiB, i.e. 8×1024² B = 8,388,608 B. That's the number you're seeing.

If you want to be able to upload files up to 1 GiB, you have to edit your php.ini file, and set [post_max_size](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) and [upload_max_filesize](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) to "1G".

Comment: problem solved, i change post_max_size and upload_max_filesize to 1000M (1GB) thank you

Comment: "1000M" is not 1GB, it is ~1.049 GB, or ~0.977 GiB. "1G" = "1024M" = 1 GiB.