# Error while uploading a new Theme to wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How should I fix the error:"Warning: POST Content-Length of 26585174 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0"
Thank you!

Comment: This is related to PHP cnofiguration. Look here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11719522/1165289

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Warning: POST Content-Length of 8978294 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719495/php-warning-post-content-length-of-8978294-bytes-exceeds-the-limit-of-8388608-b)

Answer (score 0):

You should change your php.ini setting variable.

```
upload_max_filesize = 1000M;
post_max_size = 1000M;
```

Comment: Thanks! now getting this error: `Warning: POST Content-Length of 26585178 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0
Warning: mysqli_query(): (HY000/6): Error on delete of 'C:\xampp\tmp\#sql2ed8_7_6.MYI' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied) in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wordpress\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1924
Warning: mysqli_query(): (HY000/6): Error on delete of :\xampp\tmp\#sql2ed8_7_9.MYD' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied) in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wordpress\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1924

Warning: mysqli_query(): (HY000/6): Error on delete of 'C:\.........`

Comment: now getting this: The package could not be installed. The theme is missing the style.css stylesheet.

Theme installation failed. (after reloading server)