# PHP Warning: POST Content-Length of n bytes exceeds the limit of 3145728 bytes in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php

I am quite surprise to find the above-mentioned error in my error log because I thought I have already done the necessary work to catch the error in my PHP script:

```
if ($_FILES['image']['error'] == 0)
{
 // go ahead to process the image file
}
else
{
 // determine the error
 switch($_FILES['image']['error'])
 {
  case "1":
  $msg = "Uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.";
  break;
  ....
 }
}
```

In my PHP.ini script, the relevant settings are:

```
memory_limit = 128M
post_max_size = 3M
upload_max_filesize = 500K
```

I understand that the 3M is equivalent to 3145728 bytes and that this is what that is triggering the error. If the file size is above 500k but less than 3M, the PHP script would be able to run as per normal, issuing the error message in `$msg` as per `case 1`.

How do I catch this error instead of letting the script terminate abruptly with a PHP warning when post size exceeds `post_max_size` but still well within the memory limit? I have looked at similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719495/php-warning-post-content-length-of-8978294-bytes-exceeds-the-limit-of-8388608-b), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315358/php-warning-post-content-length-of-113-bytes-exceeds-the-limit-of-1988100096-b) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279897/php-post-content-length-of-11933650-bytes-exceeds-the-limit-of-8388608-bytes), but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Why don't you wrap your function in a `try..catch` block?

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_WARNING);` to switch off PHP warnings.

Comment: @fdomig That should be the absolute last resort.

Comment: @inhan because it is better to write code that handles errors properly

Comment: @MichaelRobinson well you may disable and re-enable direct after that request again ... this is how to deal with some PHP warnings. Anyway, on a productive system you do not want to *display* any error but log these and inform the developer.

Comment: @fdomig on a production system yes. But right now the OP is developing, which is when one should strive to avoid workarounds.

Comment: @MichaelRobinson a solution is to provide your own error handler with something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1241751/246051

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found an alternative solution that does not deal with the error directly. The following code is written by a software engineer Andrew Curioso in his [blog](http://andrewcurioso.com/2010/06/detecting-file-size-overflow-in-php/):

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && empty($_POST) &&
     empty($_FILES) && $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] > 0)
{
  $displayMaxSize = ini_get('post_max_size');

  switch(substr($displayMaxSize,-1))
  {
    case 'G':
      $displayMaxSize = $displayMaxSize * 1024;
    case 'M':
      $displayMaxSize = $displayMaxSize * 1024;
    case 'K':
       $displayMaxSize = $displayMaxSize * 1024;
  }

  $error = 'Posted data is too large. '.
           $_SERVER[CONTENT_LENGTH].
           ' bytes exceeds the maximum size of '.
           $displayMaxSize.' bytes.';
}
```

As explained in his article, when the post size exceeds `post_max_size`, the super global arrays of `$_POST` and `$_FILES` will become empty. So, by testing for these and by confirming that there is some content being sent using the POST method, it can be deduced that such an error has occurred.

There is actually a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133652/how-to-gracefully-handle-files-that-exceed-phps-post-max-size), which I didn't manage to find earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You could check it with javascript first before the upload even takes place?

```
// Assumed input for file in your HTML
<input type="file" id="myFile" />


//binds to onchange event of your input field
$('#myFile').bind('change', function() {
    alert(this.files[0].size);
});
```

You can also pop a try catch around it:

```
try 
{
    if (!move_uploaded_file( 'blah blah' )) 
    {
        throw new Exception('Too damn big.');
    }
    // Can do your other error checking here...
    echo "Upload Complete!";
} 
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    die ('File did not upload: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: The user may not have javascript enabled.

Comment: +1 this might not fully solve the problem, but a good suggestion.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow Although true, but chances of that happening is 1 in a million as everything today needs JS to be enabled. Would be difficult to find someone with their JS disabled

Comment: @aspirin, I understand. But I am looking for a more reliable server side solution. You wouldn't want to do form validation client side only, would you?

Comment: Yes, I can adopt try and catch block, but is this the way to go? Because I thought exceptions are triggered due to bad coding and I want to avoid bad coding.

Comment: A to big `$_POST` size does not throw any Exception but raises a PHP Warning. You would have to provide your own error handler. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1241751/246051

Comment: @fdomig Interesting, thanks for that link! Added too my +favs for further review.

Comment: @fdomig, thanks for the link. So can anyone conclude that this error is unavoidable and therefore needs some error handling?