# PHP Warns of POST content length exceed limit

Tags: php, file-upload, warnings

I got a PHP warning which says:

> PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 2290848 bytes exceeds the limit
>   of 2097152 bytes in Unknown on line 0,

The following are my configuration:

In /etc/php.ini

```
post_max_size = 2.5M
upload_max_filesize = 500K
max_file_uploads = 5
```

In /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
LimitRequestBody 3000000
```

From the above, my post max size is supposed to be 2.5M. Why is this warning triggered at a lower limit of 2M (2097152 bytes)?

Comment: Sure it's the correct php.ini?

Comment: @AmazingDreams, yes. There is only one php.ini in /etc folder

Comment: Just because it is the only config file doesn't mean it's actually being loaded.  You can confirm the actual ini value using `ini_get()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php

Comment: Also the correct one according to `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`?

Comment: OK, or that will do it :-)

Comment: You haven't forgotten to restart the web server have you?

Comment: @AmazingDreams, phpinfo() shows it is 2.5M for both local and master value.

Comment: Similar question asked by you on july 31st. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738949/php-warning-post-content-length-of-n-bytes-exceeds-the-limit-of-3145728-bytes-i

Comment: @MarkBaker, that value has not been unchanged for a long while.

Comment: @Prabu, that is not the same question at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[post_max_size](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) is an integer, 2.5 is not.