# How to detect php's file-upload error when $_FILES is empty

Tags: php, apache, file-upload, php-ini

I try to upload files (by silex). because I was limited post's content-length in httpd-conf file:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 1M
php value post_max_size 10M
```

When I try to upload files, larger than 10M( larger than post_max_size ), I see a warning in httpd-error and the $_FILES is empty:

```
[Sat Apr 05 11:08:54.788022 2014] [:error] [pid 1165] [client ::1:44010] PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 30531496 bytes exceeds the limit of 10485760 bytes in Unknown on line 0, referer: http://somehost/somepath
```

I don't have access to the error ( even by error_get_last ) and I can't detect the problem in code.
How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: Maybe this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11745361/1700963) might help?

Comment: This tutorial will help you further.. http://blog.trofeosolution.com/index.php/blog/file-upload