# I have modified the php_ini and still get PHP warning POST Content-Length exceed the limit

Tags: php

I have changed `php.ini`, `post_max_size = 20M;`

```
php -i | grep 'post_max_file' ,post_max_size => 20M => 20M
```

After all , I still get nginx error log:

> FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 9522297 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0" while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.2.106, server: www.hinabian.com, request: "POST /image/save?editorid=id_content HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:"

Comment: Did you edit the correct file ?
Did you reboot the server after doing the modification ?

Comment: of course. I have done above all you said.

Comment: **Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/05-opcache.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-redis.ini
**

Answer (score 2):

In my case, my problem was that I'd updated the php.ini at `/etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini` instead of at `/etc/php/7.3/fpm/php.ini`.

(CLI is not the same as FPM.)

My site behaved properly after I updated the FPM php.ini and ran `sudo service php7.3-fpm restart`.