# How to fix Content-Length of * bytes exceeds the limit of * bytes

Tags: php, html

My problem is when I upload a file exceeds the limits I set in the script (5 MB) it shows this warning in the top of the website:

> Warning: POST Content-Length of 32485176 bytes exceeds the limit of 20971520 bytes in Unknown on line 0

For example here I uploaded a file more than (30 MB) but when I upload a file more than (5 MB) and less than 30 (or not that large) it doesn't show that warning and shows only the error I wanted from the code:

```
if($file_size > 5000000) { echo
    "<div>
        You Can't Upload More than 5MB of the file
    </div>";
}
```

I am working on localhost and this error is appearing every time, I know how to fix it in localhost by modifying `php.ini`, but the website is online too and this error isn't showing in the website.
Is there a way to limit the uploaded files sizes to (5 MB) and not modifying the `php.ini` file because I don't think I have the permission from the hosting company to change the Apache config for the limits.

Comment: Make sure you're updating the correct php.ini: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58999601/470749

Comment: Please don't use unrelated tags, or explain how this is a HTML or MySQL problem. Also, please share your attempts to resolve the problem. As far as I see, this is a configuration problem of PHP

Answer (score 1):

You can change it via .htaccess file in your php file directory...

`.htaccess` files are stored in the same directory as your .php files are. They modify configuration for that folder and all sub-folders. You simply use them by creating an .htaccess file in the directory of your choice (or modify it if present).

The following should enable you to increase your upload limit (if the server provider allows PHP config changes via .htaccess).

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
php_value post_max_size 105M
```

Comment: Thanks sir for replying, unfortunately the hosting company doesn't allow to change the upload max file, I have tried the code you gave:
php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
php_value post_max_size 105M

in .htaccess file, it showing error :

500 Internal Server Error

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: You have to contact your web server providers and ask to set **AllowOverride** Options for your host or to put these lines in their virtual host configuration file.

Comment: set error_reporting( E_ALL) and see if anything shows. It is not right way. but you can hide this warning.

Answer (score 1):

you just settings at php.ini

then set :

```
  upload_max_filesize = 1000M;
  post_max_size = 1000M;
```

then restart your server..

Answer (score 0):

Go to your XAMPP Directory and then go to:
`xampp\php\php` (configuration file)

Find for `post_max_size` (make sure you are at top of file)
then change

```
post_max_size = 2M To  post_max_size 1000M
upload_max_filesize = 8M To upload_max_filesize = 1000M
```

and now restart you Apache server or if still error restart Apache, MySQL too