# POST content limit exceeds at the time of theme upload

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, xampp

I am trying to upload Avada theme on my localhost server Xampp. But I am facing this error " Warning: POST Content-Length of 45168105 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0"

I know that this is because of **upload_max_filesize** but I have change it in php.ini but still getting the error. Don't know why.
Need some answers. Already googled and tried every thing

```
upload_max_filesize=1000M
post_max_size=20M
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP post\_max\_size overrides upload\_max\_filesize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754133/php-post-max-size-overrides-upload-max-filesize)

Comment: increase post max size in php.ini and restart apache

Comment: change it to 50M, but still getting the error @KevinPatel

Comment: More duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279897/post-content-length-exceeds-the-limit)

Answer (score 3):

8388608 bytes is 8M, the default limit in PHP. So i suggest you to set your php.ini as below

```
php_value post_max_size 250M
php_value upload_max_filesize 250M
php_value max_execution_time 600000
php_value max_input_time 600000
php_value memory_limit 250M
```

Note: make sure your restart your Apache server after making them.

Original :https://stackoverflow.com/a/6279945/2384642

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you didn't change `post_max_size` to equal 1000M. `upload_max_filesize` is to accept uploading files over 1000Mb, but to do that you need to upload them (via post) so, you are limiting the post size to 20Mb.

Change `post_max_size=20M` to `post_max_size=1000M` and remember you can use `K` for Kilobyte, `M` for Megabyte and `G` for Gigabyte, so you could write 1G insted of 1000M (1024M).

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) official PHP Documentation.

> Note:
>   PHP allows shortcuts for byte values, including K (kilo), M (mega) and G (giga). PHP will do the conversions automatically if you use any of these. Be careful not to exceed the 32 bit signed integer limit (if you're using 32bit versions) as it will cause your script to fail.

[Post duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754133/php-post-max-size-overrides-upload-max-filesize).

Comment: Did you restart the server ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the .htaccess file instead of your php.ini file. Like this:-

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
php_value post_max_size 50M
php_value max_execution_time 500
php_value max_input_time 500
```