# Warning: POST Content-Length of 90612004 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, laravel

I got this error

> **Warning: POST Content-Length of 90612004 bytes exceeds the limit of
>   8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0**

I've done some searches and I changed `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize`
to 150M and reset Wamp  but STILL I get this error what should I do?

Comment: have you restarted your wamp sever

Comment: where do you get that error? in the WAMP-Logs?

Comment: Checkout this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719495/php-warning-post-content-length-of-8978294-bytes-exceeds-the-limit-of-8388608-b And also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279897/post-content-length-exceeds-the-limit

Comment: @AbuHurairaLakdawala yes I did

Comment: @ManuToMatic in the browser its a form that uploads a file that is 90Mb and I get this error

Comment: @houdriwiokug seen these before , my problem is it doesn't apply changes

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 way to fix.

First - change php.ini file information.
[image]

set configurations as following.

```
   post_max_size=100M
   upload_max_filesize=100M
```

Second - use .htaccess file.

```
   php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
   php_value post_max_size 100M
```