# PHP Warning: POST Content-Length of 66192047 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes

Tags: php

im getting this error when sending a form with uploaded file.

i already put `upload_max_filesize`  and `post_max_size` to 1000M in my php.ini without any result.

Comment: restart server if not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [POST Content-Length exceeds the limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279897/post-content-length-exceeds-the-limit)

Comment: restarting server had no effect.

Comment: possible duplicate  how can i check if that's the case?

Comment: check phpinfo() whether your changes reflected or not

Comment: for your case, this question is already asked and answered. so possible duplicate

Comment: 8388608 bytes = 8M not 1000M?! Check your work...

Comment: yes in phpinfo() everythings look fine : upload_max_filesize => 1000M => 1000M   post_max_size => 1000M => 1000M

Comment: i understand what you are saying but still i checked and i got 1000M

Comment: use phpinfo() to check if the values you changed works. Maybe you have changed the cli php.ini no the one for apache/fpm? Remember to restart server after the change!

Answer (score 1):

If you did setting `php.ini` file and then restart Apache daemon or Server.

Please check your php source files and .htaccess file.

**First.**

Maybe contain `ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '8M')` or 
  `ini_set('post_max_size', '8M')`.

They can be in `index.php` file.

**Second.**

They can be in `.htaccess`file.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M
```