# Unknown POST Content-Length exceeds limit

Tags: php

```
Warning: Unknown: POST Content-Length of 49 bytes exceeds the limit of 40 bytes in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in Unknown on line 0
```

My HTML passes 4 string parameters to a a PHP trough a POST form, and when I do not enter anything I get these errors up until I get to the portion of my code that checks if a string from $_POST is empty.

I looked it up online and it was all stuff related to file uploading, but why exactly is it happening to me?

And what else should I know about creating a stable PHP script? I don't want my users to see these kinds of things. Maybe I can at the very least server one of my own pages instead of these to serve the errors to the client?

Thank you!

---

```
    <html>
    
        <body>
        
        <form action="register.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="ID" placeholder="ID"><br>
            <input type="text" name="PASS"  placeholder="Password"><br>
            <input type="text" name="UID" placeholder="ID2"><br>
            <input type="text" name="UPASS" placeholder="Password2"><br>
        
            <input type="submit" value="Register">
        </form>
        
        </body>
        
        </html>
```

[php.ini](https://pastebin.com/raw/Ad7XjxR4) file.

Comment: can you share the code ?

Comment: The HTML code? The error in my PHP script occurs right at the beginning, it's not hitting my code before warning me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [POST Content-Length exceeds the limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279897/post-content-length-exceeds-the-limit)

Comment: No. that person had users uploading too big of files, I get these errors when passing absolutely no data to the PHP script

Comment: we have to start somewhere. what you have done, we have the issue.

Comment: can you post your php.ini and the php code ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/Ad7XjxR4

Comment: can you update your question with the information ?

Comment: As I expected, and that linked post covers. `post_max_size=40` A misconfigured php.ini.

Comment: Yeah. Also, I put a die() after the <?php tag and the errors are still there, so the code seems irrelevant

Comment: What **is** your post_max_size? It's apparently 40 bytes, which is way too low.

Comment: Yeah I think that's a problem, but why is it popping up when I pass nothing and not when I pass actual strings?

Comment: You have two `post_max_size`. One is `40M`, the other `40`

Comment: That did it, at last

Comment: A POST (even empty fields) can be bigger than 40 bytes, because its including the post body and variable names to create the request. It all gets counted up. Its not just 'the values', its 'everything'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your value on the php.ini file from `post_max_size=40` to a bigger value. `40m` for example.

and restart your apache after the change is done.

Comment: You'll notice in his php.ini that it is first defined as `post_max_size=40M`, but then later in the same ini, its redefined as `post_max_size=40` ... oops.